# Unknown custom element vue js

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, nuxt.js

I've created new nuxt app
using this tutorial 
https://nuxtjs.org/guide/installation/

`vue init nuxt/starter <project-name>`

nuxt - is a server side rendering wrap which uses `vue.js`

Now I get this error:

> Unknown custom element:  - did you register the component
>   correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name"
>   option.

This is my index page:

```
<template>
    <section class="container">
        <div>
            <logo/>
            this is index page
            <p>
                <nuxt-link to="/contacts">contacts</nuxt-link>
            </p>
        </div>
    </section> </template>

<script>
    import Logo from '~components/Logo.vue'
    export default {
        components: {
            Logo,
        }
    } </script>
```

This is my Logo.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="VueToNuxtLogo">
    <div class="Triangle Triangle--two"></div>
    <div class="Triangle Triangle--one"></div>
    <div class="Triangle Triangle--three"></div>
    <div class="Triangle Triangle--four"></div>
  </div>
</template>
```

What do I do?

Comment: I guess it is caused by `<logo/>`. You should define it properly by using `logo: Logo` and use it like `<logo></logo>`.

Comment: @str doesn't help

Comment: Has `nuxt-link` been defined?

Comment: @str how do I define it?

Comment: I've just created a new project similar to yours and it worked flawlessly out of the box. Maybe try to create a new project, something might have gone wrong during the installation. I'm using node v6.3.0 and vue-cli v2.8.1